# Android access data sent with -e

Tags: java, android, command-line

According to http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/run-android-application-from-command.html, you can send extra info to an android app with the -e flag like this:

am start **-e myKey myVal** -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n my.domain.myApp/my.domain.myApp.myClass

My question is, how do I get to that data from Java? Is there something like `extraSettings.get("myKey")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access it via the intent that's used to start your Activity. So for example, say you have an Activity called `MyActivity` and you called `am start -e myKey myVal -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n my.domain.myApp/my.domain.myApp.MyActivity`. Then you'd access it in MyActivity by doing the following in the `onCreate()` method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
   Intent givenIntent = getIntent();
   String myVal = givenIntent.getExtra("myKey");
   //other code....
}
```